# Drupal 7 jQuery function call issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal-7

I am experiencing the following issue within Drupal but it is probably not entirely a Drupal specific issue.

I have the following simple javascript:

```
(function ($) {

  function testing(){
    alert('TEST function responding!');
  }

})(jQuery);
```

And I am attempting to call that function from my Drupal module using the following code:

```
drupal_add_js('jQuery(document).ready(function () { testing(); });',
  array('type' => 'inline', 'scope' => 'footer', 'weight' => 5)
);
```

However, I get an error saying **Uncaught ReferenceError: testing is not defined**

I want to take advantage of jQuery's abilities within that function which is why I am not using an ordinary JavaScript file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to extend your function to jQuery variable, you can do this:

```
if( !jQuery.testing ){

jQuery.extend( {
    testing: function() { 
        console.log("Calling from extend function in jQuery");
    }
});
}
```

And to call it:

```
drupal_add_js('jQuery(document).ready(function () { jQuery.testing(); });',
  array('type' => 'inline', 'scope' => 'footer', 'weight' => 5)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty answer: the scope in which you're defining `testing()` and in which you are calling it are not the same. You could define testing the global scope, and then it will work, although this is not best practice for a large application.

```
(function ($) {
    window.testing = function(){
        alert('TEST function responding!');
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you storing the first part of the code in an external JavaScript? use drupal_add_js to reference that e.g.,

```
drupal_add_js('js/external.js');

//external.js
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
window.testing = function(){
    alert('TEST function responding!');
// The useful part of this is the ability to use $ from now on. e.g., $('body').hide();
}
});
});
```

then add your JavaScript

```
drupal_add_js('jQuery(document).ready(function () { testing(); });',
array('type' => 'inline', 'scope' => 'footer', 'weight' => 5)
);
```